# How can I show the full size of Image?

Tags: android, image, gridview

I'm new here and new in programming Android. I found this example (below is the example) on a site in internet, It's a great tutorial! What do I want to achieve is when once I clicked a picture on the GridView I want to show the full size of the Image.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    void add(String path) {
        itemList.add(path);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                    // attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220,
                220);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        return imageView;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth,
            int reqHeight) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        return bm;
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(

    BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height
                        / (float) reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

}

ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/test/";

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);` change the padding

Comment: and, what is the question? Have You faced some issues with provided code?

Comment: the code is great, what do I want to achieve is when I clicked a picture on Gridview, I want to show the full image, maybe I need to create another activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the image to the other activity to show it in full view.

To pass the image from Your main Activity. USe following code:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

ImageView img = ia.getView(position, v, parent);
                img.buildDrawingCache(); 
                Bitmap bmap = img.getDrawingCache();
                Intent intent = new Intent(HelloGridView.this,
                        Imageviewer.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                //bundle.putParcelable("image", bmap);
                    String par=myimageadpter.getpath(position);
                             bundle.putParcelable("imagepath", par);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });
```

In other activity use this code to show the passed image:

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
             bmp=bundle.getParcelable("image");
            ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            d =new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
            img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

If you pass path. the second activity look like this:

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

String s=bundle.getParcelable("imagepath");
 Bitmap Imagefrompath = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s);
            ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            img.setImageBitmap(Imagefrompath );
```

Comment: ok I'll try this one,. How can I retrieve it to other activity? I created another activity.

Comment: I have a question in the line ImageView img = ia.getView(position, v, parent); What is the ia?

Comment: Object of image adapter. In your case it is myImageAdapter

Comment: It's working, but the only problem is that it's not showing the full size of image. It's like that its zooming in the picture in gridview.

Comment: then pass the path between the activities instead of image

Comment: How can I pass the path do you have another example for this?, thank you for the first solution.

Comment: change the parcelable line to bundle.putParcelable("imagepath",itemList.get(position) );

Comment: see my edited answer.. And if you found solution by answer accept it by tick the "Correct"mark at right to my answer.

Comment: I have red line in putParcelable.

Comment: add this method in imageadapter public String getpath(int position)
{
return itemList.get(position);
} and see my edited answer

Comment: I added that line but still red line on it. Thank you for helping.

Comment: It's still the redline in putParcelable.

Comment: ok here's what I did, instead of putParcelable. I changed it to putString because the getPath in Adapter is string. It fixes the red line. thank you so much.