# Display the date of the picture when it was taken?

Tags: android, date, imageview

I want to display the date of the picture when it was taken on my ImageView., Let's say that I have pictures on my girdview. once I clicked it, it'll go to other activity and display the full size of the image. Now in that activity, I need to display the date when it was taken. Any Ideas?

Comment: Any image stored in the device's `MediaStore` has along with it a `DATE_TAKEN` field that you can include in your query and then display on the screen.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html  To answer the question of "How", we would need a lot more information about how you are accessing the images in the first place.

Comment: ok Im accesing the image as what my previous question, In this way, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474667/how-can-i-show-the-full-size-of-image). By ExternalStorageDirectoryPath.

Comment: There should be lot's of tutorials showing just this, all in one answer is quite a lot.

Comment: Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possible ways I can see of doing this on Android.  The first being the file modified date which can be achieved like so:

```
String pathToFile = "Your file path";
File file = new File(pathToFile);
if(file.exists()) {
    long date = file.lastModified();
    /* Do your modified date stuff here */
}
```

The other way would be to check the EXIF data on the image to get the date the picture was taken if that information is available:

```
ExifInterface intf = null;
try {
    intf = new ExifInterface(path);
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if(intf == null) {
    /* File doesn't exist or isn't an image */
}

String dateString = intf.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
/* Do your date/time stuff here */
```

Just a note, the Exif data for an image might not contain a date.  Most phone cameras and commercial cameras will add a date/time Exif entry but images created on a computer are less likely to have Exif data.  Also, Exif date/time isn't formatted very nice.  Example Exif date/time string: `2012:06:02 14:33:46` (taken from an image I took with my Nexus S)

Comment: ok thank you. how can i add one of that here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480724/how-to-get-the-date-taken-and-display-it)?

Comment: You can't display the text directly onto the ImageView.  You'll have to make a more complex layout (maybe a RelativeLayout with an ImageView and TextView in it) and populate the individual elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply reading each image off external storage as a `File`, then `File` has a method called `lastModified()` to get the modified date of the file.  While this is not necessarily the date that file was created, for an immutable file like an image it most likely is.

```
for (File file : files) {
    //This is the date the file was modified/created
    long date = file.lastModified();
    //You can even convert it to a Date if you want
    Date fileData = new Date(date);
}
```

If your application is the one creating the images on external storage and you absolutely need the initial creation date only of the file, you had best store that information yourself in a local database when the image is created.  This is what the `MediaStore` does for the framework.

Comment: ok thank you for the reply, do you have example? please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480724/how-to-get-the-date-taken-and-display-it.

Comment: Just call `file.lastModified()` to get the value for each file you need to read/display.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` to combine both the `ImageView` and a `TextView` with the date, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7707452/642161).

Comment: thank you for the reply, but I don't have yet the date taken of the picture.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you should open another question. This question's title talks about "display", never did you mention you couldn't get the Date yet.

Comment: Ok, I created a question regarding that.