# How to get the date of my chosen image in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Here's the code I'm using to choose an image from the gallery and display it using image view. Now I'm stuck on how to get the date.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.waterconsumptionview, container, false);

    imageToUpload = (ImageView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagetoUpload);
    bUpload = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bUploadImage);
    bUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case  R.id.bUploadImage:
                    Intent uploadimage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(uploadimage, RESULT);
                    break;
                case  R.id.bProcess:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        imageToUpload.setImageURI(selectedImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: What date? The date of image?

Comment: Sorry, the date of the image taken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Date Taken and Display it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480724/how-to-get-the-date-taken-and-display-it)

Answer (score 1):

## Try this hope it was helpful for you

- If date created not available then go for last modified date.
- make your `ExitInterface` is in `try-catch` to avoid `crash`

---

```
File file = new File(filePath);
 if(file.exists()) //Extra check,          Just to validate the given path
 {
ExifInterface intf = null;
try 
{
    intf = new ExifInterface(filePath);
    if(intf != null)
    {
        String dateString = intf.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
        Log.i("Dated : "+ dateString.toString()); //Dispaly dateString. You can do/use it your own way        
    }
}
catch
{
}
if(intf == null)
{
    Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
    Log.i("Dated : "+ lastModDate.toString());//Dispaly lastModDate. You can do/use it your own way
}
}
```

---

## Happy to help you

Comment: You mean the path where the image is right? Ty, gonna try this